# Need a comand to auto extract wifi extractor for my project "auto wifi extractor"

Tags: batch-file, cmd, wifi

So i am making a wifi extractor for my personal project. I am using a batch file and i cant seem to find a command that will show the wifi passwords. So far i came up with "netsh show all" but that does how show the security key, i also know "netsh show profiles name=[name] key=clear" but that requires user intervention, which is against the point of the auto wifi extractor.

I am planning to use the command to get the info and >>[text file name] to send the info to a destined file.

This might be a very common and noob command, but i tried googling around with it and cant seem to find a suitable command. Plus i am trying to self teach myself how to code and i am starting with batch and this wifi extractor is my first project.

Comment: Why does 'netsh show profile' require user intervention?

Comment: It requires user intervenrion because you have to insert the name of the wifi to get the password. Or is there a way to auto fill in the section for the name=[name]?